# How to check whether a select box is empty using JQuery/Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile, jquery-selectbox

I have a select box that is being populated dynamically from a database. As of right now the population of this check box is working flawlessly.

I have added functionality that consists of a button which on click calls `isSelextBoxEmpty`. The job of this function is to know whether this particular check box has been populated or not; if it has not then it will simply do nothing.

**My problem** is in determining whether this select box is empty or not.

Here is a very simplified example of what I am dealing with:

```
<li>
    <label for="fruit_name">Fruit</label>
    <select name="some_fruit" id="fruit_name" onclick="populate_box('fruit', this);">
    </select>
</li>
```

My function, which is called from a separate button, looks like this:

```
function isSelextBoxEmpty(selectBoxId) {
    var selected_value = $('#fruit_name');

    /* More options... still testing the proper way:
    var selected_value = $('#fruit_name').text;
    var selected_value = $('#fruit_name').value;
    var selected_value = $('#fruit_name').length;
    var selected_value = $('#fruit_name option:selected', this);
    var selected_value = document.getElementById('fruit_name');
    var selected_value = document.getElementById('fruit_name').length;
    var selected_value = document.getElementById('fruit_name').value;
    var selected_value = document.getElementById('fruit_name').innerHTML;
    */

    if (selected_value) {
        alert("NOT null, value: " + selected_value);
        // do something
    }
}
```

Don't worry about what this does and how it does it. Right now what matters to me is that I can't check whether or not the checkbox is empty, I am just not sure how to go about it. I have read a lot through forums and documentation but there are many implications in doing this since it depends on the implementation itself.

For instance using `document.getElementById(...)...` will not necessarily return false and it depends on how you use it. Also using `$("#someID")...` in jQuery may or may not produce the desired results. I have already tried many different times as you can see in the *commented lines*, all of which can be evaluated in the `if(...)` statement.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 110, accepted):

To check whether select box has any values:

```
if( $('#fruit_name').has('option').length > 0 ) {
```

To check whether selected value is empty:

```
if( !$('#fruit_name').val() ) {
```

Comment: I awarded the answer to you because you got it right before Claudio, but actually Claudio also got it right just a few seconds after you did... THANKS both of you! I wish I could split the reward.

Comment: The latter code is not correct. Infact, if you try it with a select box you receive null as the val(), but @if( !$('#fruit_name').val() )@ returns TRUE.

Comment: Well I'm trying to take away my downvote because this is correct, but stackoverflow won't let me. Pretty lame. Sorry for the downvote, it should be an upvote.

Comment: @Engineer Thanks for the great answer, which I was really looking for...

Answer (score 16):

One correct way to get selected value would be

```
var selected_value = $('#fruit_name').val()
```

And then you should do

```
if(selected_value) { ... }
```

Answer (score 2):

Another correct way to get selected value would be using this selector:

```
$("option[value="0"]:selected")
```

Best for you!

Answer (score 1):

Check this answer its tested and working well

```
if( !$('#id').val() ) {
   // stuff here
}
```

Comment: This exact answer has already been given to the question.

Comment: correct, this is similar to the above answers but you should change `#id` to  `#fruit_name`